# Can't Pickle Wrapper Class Object

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pickle, python-multiprocessing

All, I'm trying to parallelize some code using multiprocessing, and I've stripped my code down such that commenting the line of my main class

```
self.obs = Observer(self.guess)
```

causes the system to run error free. If I write

```
obs = Observer(self.guess)
```

It works, but if I write self.obs, I get

```
TypeError: can't pickle Observer objects
```

Here is the entire class I'm trying to import. It is just a wrapper for ephem.Observer, which had the same error when importing.

```
import numpy as np 
from req import SETTINGS
from req.helpers import load_db, pack_into_vector, create_observer 

class Observer:
        def __init__(self, beta=np.zeros((2,))):
            self.observer = create_observer(beta)
            return

        def __getstate__(self):
            return {'observer': self.observer}
```

The error occurs on p.start() where

```
p = Process(target=selector,args=(first_guess, recording_queue, guess_queue))
```

Comment: More information needed: what is `p`, and what does its `start()` method do? You may benefit from reading [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) about asking questions. Then perhaps edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved this. I guess the issue was with all of the self.___ methods/attributes of my selector class. I created an additional class, selector_wrapper, with an init method that created and ran the selector class. This worked perfectly.

In summary, creating a wrapper class with no methods other than init, and with no attributes, fixed the problem!